# More objects in memory with same id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku

In my rails app (v: 3.1) deployed on heroku I am getting more objects of same id in memory.
my heroku console log:

```
>> Project.find_all_by_id(92).size
=> 2
>> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('select * from projects where id=92').to_a.size
=> 1
```

How is this possible? What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you also post the SQL statements that are generated?

Comment: More diagnostics you could post that would help narrow it down: `Project.find_all_by_id(92).method(:size).source_location` (Did something override .size?) and `Project.find_all_by_id(92).to_a.size` (Does it work when it's not an association?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

There is apparently no duplicate entry in your database according to your SQL query.

Maybe **size** or **length** method in your class Project has been overridden. I have tried **find_all_by_id** and the SQL query seems to be correct.

```
1.9.2-p180 :006 > Script.find_all_by_id(1).size
  Script Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "scripts".* FROM "scripts" WHERE "scripts"."id" = 1
 => 1
```

**Hint**

If you want to count records you should do it this way

```
Script.where(id: 1).size
  (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "scripts" WHERE "scripts"."id" = 1
 => 1
```

Because, as you can see, **the count is performed by your database** and not by ruby itself. For a dozen of rows you won't see the difference, but if you have thousands or millions...

Comment: Yep, I'd bet you have a column named 'size' in your projects table, or some smart guy wrote: `def size; to_do_items.count; end` or similar.  :-)

Comment: @Irongaze.com A column named 'size' could be a possibility... I didn't think about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):023:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('select count(*) from users where    address_id = 22').fetch_hash
=> {"count(*)"=>"4"}
irb(main):024:0> User.find_all_by_address_id(22).size
=> 4
```

you'd better lookup document about Mysql::Result first

http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql/2.8.1/frames